# Problem on adding Django app to installed apps and can't migrate

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I'm trying to use visual studio for my Django project. My visual studio version is 2017, my Python version is 3.6 and my Django version at the beginning is 1.1.18.
Then I upgrade it to 2.1.5. I make an app then add it to installed apps. But when I migrate the project get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "E:\Django_Try\Test4\Test4\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'saeed'
The interactive Python process has exited.
The interactive Python process has exited.
>>>
```

it seems can' identify my app.

my setting:

```
"""
Django settings for Test4 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '79c97724-a0e9-44f0-bffd-e255d60e5460'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'saeed',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Test4.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Test4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

[image: project file structure]

it seems can' identify my app.

Please inform me.

Saeed

Comment: Have you finished migration to 2.1.5 already or this is what you are doing now? And please share your Test4 directory structure.

Comment: you mean I share the setup file? or another thing?

Comment: Can you please explain more about what I share?

Comment: Please share your directory structure and your `settings.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** It looks like you've renamed your main/base app (the one that contains `settings.py`) from `Test4` to `saeed`. You do not need to register the base application in a Django project since it is already the entry-point for the program. It looks like the rest of your `settings.py` file is configured for the base app being called `Test4` rather than `saeed` (you can tell because of `ROOT_URLCONF = 'Test4.urls'`, for example). You can read more about projects and applications in Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications).

Since it's common practice to have your base app share the same name as your project I'd recommend changing the name of the `saeed` directory (back) to `Test4`.

If you want to create a new app you can run:

```
python manage.py startapp saeed
```

So your project file structure will look something like this:

```
Test4/     # project directory
  saeed/   # your app
    migrations/
    models.py
    apps.py
  Test4/   # base app for the site
    settings.py
    urls.py
  manage.py
  requirements.txt
```

Then put your models in `saeed` instead of `Test4`. So your project directory `Test4/`, will contain `Test4/`, `saeed/`, and `manage.py`, among other things. After you create this new app, the following will work:

**Original Answer:**
Make sure your `saeed/apps.py` is configured properly, for example:

```
# saeed/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class SaeedConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "saeed"
    verbose_name = "Saeed"
```

Then you'll want to change that line in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings from just `"saeed"` to

```
"saeed.apps.SaeedConfig"
```

See the [docs on configuring applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) for more on this.

Comment: But I still get the same error!! Django cant identify the new app!!

Comment: @S.pdl can you share your file structure? That link you provided does not seem to show anything

Comment: I changed it : https://drive.google.com/open?id=13w1VydaXz1vB3NRHQl3_bvx2LMrLIGKq      Please let me know what you think. Also I can share my file.

Comment: @S.pdl okay I've worked out the issue and updated my answer

Comment: You can download the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AijcwE_txBtUX79OzVP1-NPtyjHdbnXB

Comment: I made a blank project at the beginning which contains the nessecery files and the name was "Test4" then add an app to the project which contains the files like model and view.

Comment: @S.pdl ok this looks fine except that you need to move the `saeed` directory up one level. It should be a child of the Django project directory `Test4` (not to be confused with the `Test4` base app that it's in currently). Checkout the little bit I just added about what the final directory structure should look like

Comment: @HenryWoody, Is it always necessary to add new created application to INSTALLED_APPS ? I am able to run my new application on development server without adding it..

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is the incorrect file location hierarchy.

Should be so, for example.

```
project
    mysite
        settings.py
        ...
    saeed
        makemigrations
        models.py
        apps.py
        ...
    manage.py
```

[Read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

Comment: But this is the default file structure visual studio makes for Django files!!